# How to add `apply plugin` to build.gradle in Codename One Android project in order to add native library?

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I looked through the [Advanced Topics](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) on  Codename One's website but haven't found anything on how to implement instructions for native Android libraries that require adding `apply plugin:[plugin name here]` to the application's top-level `build.gradle` file.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no current way of adding a new plugin entry, I've added a new build hint `android.gradlePlugin` which should be available in the next server update (Friday 29th of September 2017).

You should be able to use it like this (untested):

```
android.gradlePlugin=apply plugin: 'pluginA';apply plugin: 'pluginB';
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this update. Just to clarify, will the untested build hint work before Friday?

Comment: No, it won't. You will have to wait until Friday to get it to work.

Comment: Is there a way to inject an "apply plugin" statement after the "dependencies" section ? I'm trying to add the "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in order for the firebase messaging to initialize at startup and apparently this needs to be added after the dependencies.  Thanks.

Comment: Google services is already included in Codename One apps by default